# business methods in playframework contolles

Tags: model-view-controller, playframework, business-logic

Could somebody explain is it possible to have potected, pivate methods in playfamewok's contolles except:

> public static void method-action-name() {}

For example if I would have method like this:

> protected static int doSomeWork() {}

and this method would be invoked in **method-action-name**() ..

```
public static void method-action-name() {
  ...
  int resul = doSomeWork();
  ...
}
```

I do not want to have long action-method, so I would like to split it to smaller ones, and then reuse it in other action-methods.

I mean is it ok (from playframework's point of view) to have such method in controller side instead of having them in domain classes? In Spring Framework, we use BP (business process) beans for that, for example.

Is it ok to have such helper methods for business methods in playframework controllers ?

***Added after having answer & comments:***
For example if I have SearchController class then for that class would be nice to have methods like **preSearch1()**,  **preSearch2()** what **search()** method would use, but if I move these methods (1,2) to another class then it should be class with name like **SearchHelper** then? in package named **/src/helpers**.. not very nice because they related to search too. But maybe then into **/src/bp/SearchBP** (bp=business-process). And then in **controllers/Search** i use **/bp/SearchBP** that use some Model object with .save() DAO methods (SearchBP can use Domain methods and Search class can use Domain methods as well)

The question here: what class ant package would be nice for those methods? (i just did watch it in examples - there alway very simple usage of controllers that use domain object that why i ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, you can. Controllers are normal classes, you can add whatever you want. It may not be recommended to clutter them with helper methods, I personally would move them to another class, but you can do what you say.

**ANSWER TO EDIT:**

The name of the package is "irrelevant", won't change it too much :). You can put them under controllers.support.search which would mean controllers.support is a package with helper classes and the subpackage search contains helper classes and methods related to search.

One alternative (which I like more) is to create a Service layer for that, in a "services" package. You seem to come from a Spring background, so it should come naturally to you. These services are instantiated in the controller as required, or maybe just used via static methods, and do the main business logic. That way the controller only tackles the "higher level" logic.

Another alternative is to move as much of that logic as possible into the Model (avoidid the [Anemic Domain Model](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html)), and using the Model classes from the controller.

As most decisions in development, which one is better depends on your experience, possible impact/limitations in the codebase, practices in your project... anyway, you can always refactor. Just choose the one that you are more used to (it seems to be Services approach) and code away :)

Comment: Completely agree! Generally, those utilities are simple classes with static functions and can be stored in src and not in controllers for ex.

Comment: thx! see: 'Added after having comments' i have added addition question.

Answer (score 1):

Any behaviour that's complicated enough to be described as "business logic" (rather than "presentation logic") belongs in the model, not the controller. If your model does nothing but map to/from a set of database tables, then it isn't doing its job properly. Things like permissions and access control, in particular, should be enforced by the model.

Comment: I decided do NOT use Anemic Domain Model, i.e. using all methods that related to specific domain/model. I investigated this topic and think it fit my needs